# Visual Studio 2010 erroneously thinks it's being run in compatibility mode on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, visual-studio-2010

When starting setup.exe on my Windows 7 RTM x64, I get the following error:

> Visual Studio 2010 cannot run in Compatibility Mode

I know that and it does make sense.

However, I didn't run it in compatibility mode. Nor is this compatibility mode active on the setup.exe.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found [this website](http://www.touchfirst.com/Blog/44-solved-visual-studio-setup-cannot-run-in-compatibility-mode-error-when-installing-windows-phone-7-developer-tools-rtm-vm_webexe.aspx) though, and it's working:

> I found a workaround by performing the following steps:
>
> - Created a folder called "setup" at the root (c:\setup)
> - Moved the vm_web.exe file to the new folder (c:\setup\vm_web.exe)
> - Run it from the new location.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 (Professional Edition) on Windows 7 RTM x64 with no problems. I would attempt to download the setup again to see if that fixes it. If you are using the web bootstrapper it is a fairly small download.

Comment: Compensated the downvote, the report of a working VS on x64 is useful.

Comment: Seconded. I just installed VS2010 Beta 2 Ultimate on a 64-bit Windows 7 VM with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Old problem but still occur.

`Run in compatibility` is inherited down the 'running' chain. You have to start setup.exe from a Windows Explorer. Running it from a file manager - like Total Commander - won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Visual Studio 2010 you are using a 32 bit version? It can be that the OS is trying to run it in compatibility mode (i.e. 32 bit App on 64 bit OS).

Answer (score 0):

Goto **\Setup\** folder on the installation CD/ISO then find **setup.exe** click on *Properties->Compatibility->Change for all users* and uncheck *Run in compatibility for..* radio-button. Do the same with **setup.exe** in the disk root folder.